# Source IP Whitelist Kubernetes ingress GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there anyway to filter on source-ip on the kubernetes ingress in GCE? I have tried the ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: but doesnt seems to be working in GCE.

Answer (score 2):

I guess You are trying to use this feature with GCE native controller instead NGINX? This works with NGINX only at the moment.

NGINX Controller configuration: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/nginx/configuration.md

Example configuration of ingress :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whitelist
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.1.1.1/24"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: whitelist.test.net
  http:
    paths:
    - path: /
    backend:
      serviceName: webserver
      servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Can GCE run a NGINX container that implements the whitelisting? Replacing the GCE native controller. How would you do that?

Comment: @brunobowden did you figure this out? I came across [this](https://zihao.me/post/cheap-out-google-container-engine-load-balancer/) if still any of your interest. But I found it rather annoying to put in place...

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. We ended up going with a local cluster in the end. If you're doing a cloud based cluster, something else to consider is Google's IAP - Identity Aware Proxy: https://cloud.google.com/iap/

Comment: This is great but it's not working for GKE. Why isn't this working? It should work but that annotation does literally nothing. I see no FW rules created in GCP for a source range that I specified.